# How to implement localization in Extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs, internationalization

I am using `Ux.locale.Manager` class to implement localization. After change the language from the dropdown and call `.updateLocale(value)` method and reload the page using `window.location.reload()`, it will again pick the previous default language.

What is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add the `afterrender` listener to your language selector with some code to detect the language parameter from your url like this:

```
listeners    : {
    afterrender : function(component) {
        var url = window.location.search,
            urlParams = Ext.Object.fromQueryString(url);
        if (urlParams.language) component.setValue(urlParams.language);
    },
    change : function(cb, value) {
        Ux.locale.Manager.updateLocale(value);
    }
}
```

And make sure you append the language parameter to the url before you reload it.

**OPTION 2:** You could do the same thing with cookies

```
listeners    : {
    afterrender : function (component) {
        var language = Ext.util.Cookies.get("language");
        if (language) {
            component.setValue(language);
        }
    },
    change : function(cb, value) {
        Ux.locale.Manager.updateLocale(value);
        Ext.util.Cookies.set("language", value);
    }
}
```